# How does Harry Kim get back into phase with the rest of the Voyager crew?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

At the end of the Voyager episode "Deadlock", Harry crossed the boundary between the two vessels with an arm band because he was out of phase.

- **Is he now living his entire life out of phase?**
- **Does he have to wear that arm band for the rest of his life (as well as the baby)?**
- **How did he and the baby get in phase with the rest of the ship?**

Answer (score 3):

There's two (related) questions here. I'll try to answer both;

### Does Harry need to carry on wearing the armband?

No, absolutely not. The armband seems to be needed to prevent the user from dying while **crossing** between the two quantum states, not to continue living on the other side. Think of it as a key rather than a scuba suit.

> **JANEWAY 2:** *Rig another one, Ensign. I'm going with her.*
>
> **KIM 2:** *This should protect you **from the spatial transition.***

Note that once he's on the other side, he's freely able to walk around without the armband, as we see in the final scene of the same episode:

[image]

### Is he out of phase forever?

Yes. Although it's not made clear in the show, he and the baby never return to phase. This is referenced in the follow up novel trilogy "[String Theory](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager_-_String_Theory)", set between Seasons 3 and 4:

> “Without more data as to the source of the altered engrams, it would
>   be difficult,” the Doctor said simply. “There are many differences
>   between your species which could account for… **What is this?**” the
>   Doctor interrupted himself.
>
> “What?”
>
> **“There is a subtle phase variation in the molecular structure of Naomi
>   Wildman which she does not share with you, her mother, or Mr. Neelix.
>   Can you account for this?”**
>
> A theory was formulating in Janeway’s mind and the Doctor’s discovery
>   crystallized it. **“Almost two years ago, the day Naomi was born, in
>   fact, our ship encountered a subspace scission and every particle of
>   matter on board was duplicated, including the crew. The Naomi who was
>   born on this ship did not survive, but the duplicate child did, and
>   before the other ship was destroyed, she was brought on board.”**

Comment: How does this affect them? Does being out of phase have any effect? Wouldn't it make them invisible? Why would you assume that the armband only helped with walking through the portal? The phased ship was completely invisible to the Vidiians. It was difficult for the two enterprises to even find each other, let alone communicate. Why wouldn't being out of phase have the same issue for an individual.

Comment: @JMFB - That's a very good point. I'm guessing (and this is a pure guess) that the presence of V1 pushed V2 further out of phase, creating the invisibility. With V1 destroyed, V2 rephased. But since Harry was already from V1, his phase was slightly different. Not enough to create the invisibility effect but enough to be recordable.

Comment: @JMFB - Kim states that the armband will help with "**the transition**" (e.g. the damage caused by the rift itself).

Comment: Rephased automatically? I understand that is speculation, but how would that work? What force of nature would cause a Rephase? Do you believe there's some natural force that causes things out of phase within our universe to want to be in phase? I'm not even sure that last sentence made sense, lol.

Comment: @JMFB - In my head, the two voyagers *want* to return to normal phase but they exert some kind of pressure on each other, keeping them both out of phase. When one is destroyed, the other re-enters normal phase.

Comment: So your understanding is that both ships are out of phase? So then how would either access the anti-matter? Your belief is that Phase has to do with pressure of some sort? Do you have any info on that or is it simply conjecture?

Comment: @JMFB - Pure conjecture. In my head, one is below the water (and doesn't have access to antimatter) and one is above the water (with access to antimatter). Both want to reach the surface (normality) but can't because the other is in the way. When the other is destroyed, the surface is attainable for the survivor.